# Java- How to add more textfields by clicking a button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I have created a `frame` in Java which has some `textfields and buttons` in it. Assuming that user wants more textfields (for example to add more data), I want to put a `button` and when a user clicks `the button`, then a new `textfield` should appear. then user can fill data in it and again by clicking that `button` another `textfield` should appear.
How can I do this ? What code I need to write for the button to show more and more text fields by clicking button? 
Thank you !

Comment: May you please provide more info related to what your present state of the code looks like ? So that one can guess as to where this newly created `JTextField` must come for it to look pleasing on the Screen. And Please do provide more info related to whether you are working with `AWT/Swing/JavaFX` ? These inputs might can provide you better insight :-)

Comment: I am working with Swing. the problem is I can not access more JTextFields by Clicking a Jbutton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be wise that instead of adding components to your `JFrame` directly, you add them to a `JPanel`. Though related to your problem, have a look at this small example, hopefully might be able to give you some hint, else ask me what is out of bounds.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JFrameExample
{   
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private String nameTField;
    private int count;

    public JFrameExample()
    {
        nameTField = "tField";
        count = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        button = new JButton("Add JTextField");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                tfield = new JTextField();
                tfield.setName(nameTField + count);
                count++;
                frame.add(tfield);
                frame.revalidate();  // For JDK 1.7 or above.
                //frame.getContentPane().revalidate(); // For JDK 1.6 or below.
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new JFrameExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the piece of code I have wrote, I expect by clicking the button4, a new textfield will appear ! it does not work ! ohhh                        private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


        jButton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           JTextField newTextField= new JTextField();

           NewJFrame a = new NewJFrame();

            a.add(newTextField);
           a.validate();
           a.repaint();
           
        }

Comment: No no, what you doing inside this `actionPerformed()` method is wrong. What you doing is - **You are creating a new JTextField along with that you are creating a new JFrame also, and you adding this JTextField to this new JFrame (which you never showed to the user by writing a.setVisible(true) anywhere), though you never added this new JTextField to your previous JFrame, which was visible, hence this new addition is not visible anywhere since the JFrame on which you added this JTextField is also new and you never set this to visible anywhere.**

Comment: Moreover, `revalidate()/repaint()` is not to be used anywhere, instead whenever there is a change, in terms of adding new component or removing a component from already visible component, only then this `revalidate()/repaint()` is to be used, but not in the manner you used it. Moreover, it would be wise, that instead of pasting your code to the comments, you edit your question with the same and add that code part to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that you have a main container called `panel` and a button variable `button` which is already added to `panel`, you can do:

```
// handle the button action event
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // create the new text field
    JTextField newTextField = new JTextField();
    // add it to the container
    panel.add(newTextField);
    panel.validate();
    panel.repaint();
  }
});
```

When adding the new text field, you may need to mention some layout related characteristics, depending on the layout manager you are using (for instance if you use `GridBagLayout`, you will need to specify the constraints).

Comment: thank you.  I have JFrame instead of panel. So I replaced panel.add(newTextField);
    panel.validate();                                                               with "JFrame". but it does not work. I click the button but no text box will add to the frame. sorry I am new to java and this is my first app ;) . thanks

Comment: +1 for this nicely crafted snippet, though sometimes `repaint()` is also required when adding components to an already visible container.

Comment: Here is the piece of code I have wrote, I expect by clicking the button4, a new textfield will appear ! it does not work ! ohhh private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { jButton4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ JTextField newTextField= new JTextField(); NewJFrame a = new NewJFrame(); a.add(newTextField); a.validate(); a.repaint(); }