# Create new TextField by pressing button

Tags: java, jbutton, jtextfield

I wrote the following code that is supposed to create a new TextField every time the button is pressed, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

```
private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    JTextField extend = new JTextField();
    extend.setText("new text field");

    varPanel.add(extend);
    varPanel.revalidate();
    varPanel.repaint();
}
```

The name of the panel where I'm trying to make a new TextField is called varPanel.

Comment: have you tried using `repaint()` directly in the `JFrame`? May works

Comment: A similar question already exists and it has a complete working answer. See - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12255711/3896066

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java- How to add more textfields by clicking a button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251618/java-how-to-add-more-textfields-by-clicking-a-button)

Comment: Can you rather show us a full code so that we can know the coordination between your methods.